# Alias a method multiple times

Tags: ruby, alias-method

I wish to put two aliases for one original method, but i don't see the ability of `alias_method` to do multiple aliases at once, rather one by one.

So is there a possibility to change from this:

```
alias_method :aliased_first_method, :first_method
alias_method :aliased_first_method?, :first_method
```

to something like this:

```
alias_method [:aliased_first_method, :aliased_first_method?], :first_method
```

I'm not interested in creating custom methods.

Comment: I don't see much sense in that, but if you want to have a one-liner, you could do: `[:aliased_first_method, :aliased_first_method?].each {|name| alias_method name, :first_method}` (and put that into another method in `Class`, to give it a name if you want)

Comment: it makes sense if you have the upper code repeated two times in a row.

Answer (score 20):

I do not think there is a better way than just using each:

```
[:aliased_first_method, :aliased_first_method?].each{|ali| alias_method ali, :first_method}
```

**Edit 2021 Ruby 2.7+**

```
%i[aliased_first_method aliased_first_method?].each{ alias_method _1, :first_method]}
```

Comment: Not what i was looking for, but thank you. I thought maybe Ruby has something built in by default

Comment: I understand your desire, but this answer is correct. AFAIK, there is no built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [docs and source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) of `alias_method`, I would say that what you want is **not** possible without a custom method.

(Just had to answer my almost namesake :))

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers, we are using this approach for something quite similar:

```
module HasBulkReplies
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    # Defines responses to multiple messages
    # e.g. reply_with false, to: :present?
    #      reply_with "",    to: %i(to_s name description)
    #      reply_with true,  to: %i(empty? nothing? void? nix? nada? meaning?)
    def reply_with(with, to:)
      [to].flatten.each do |message|
        define_method message do
          with
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This defines a DSL that allows us to:

```
class Work
  class Codes
    class NilObject
      include HasBulkReplies
      include Singleton

      reply_with true,
        to: :nil?

      reply_with false,
        to: %i(
          archaeology?
          childrens?
          educational_purpose?
          geographical?
          historical?
          interest_age?
```